# Find smallest rectangle divided into figures so each figure has 5 neighbours

Tags: geometry, optimization, polyomino, dissection

The following 3x4 rectangle can be cut into pieces along grid lines, so that each piece has exactly three neighbors:

[image]

> **Problem:** Find the smallest rectangle on the integer grid that can be cut into pieces along grid lines, so that each piece has exactly **five** neighbors.

Pieces are neighbors, if their boundaries touch; touching in a corner doesn't count.

Comment: I'm guessing we should use at least 8 colours? Maybe 13, 18...

Comment: @dmg You mean figures? Colours do not matter. Why do you think so?

Comment: You need at least 12 figures. Probably 12 figures gives the minimum, but it's annoying to optimize the rectangle size.

Comment: I thought of this as a planar graph, where "points of touch" are edges, which gave 8 figures, but I made a typo in my formulae and it should be 12 as @Lopsy said. I think that this is a bit more constrained than a planar graph, but am not really sure

Comment: Actually, I thought up this puzzle when was reading about planar graphs.

Comment: Damn, should have stuck with my original idea.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How's this?

[image]

I got this by square-izing the icosahedron graph:

[image]

Comment: I had solution of the same size and found with same manner. How about proof that this is minimal?

Comment: @Lopsy: Could you expand on how you "square-ized" the graph? The graph has 12 nodes, which I guess matches the 12 colours in your rectangle and I can see the "similarity". But I'm not sure about the *procedure* you've used for "square-izing".

Comment: No formal procedure, I just tried to squeeze it all into a square grid, starting from the center. Not sure how to approach a proof of minimality.

Comment: Does anybody know the treewidth of the icosahedron graph? If the treewidth is $n$, then a rectangle containing it needs to have height and width at least $n$. I looks like it has treewidth 5 but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Lopsy The treewidth is $6$: https://houseofgraphs.org/graphs/1186

Answer (score 13):

Here is a proof that $12$ is the smallest possible number of regions in any feasible solution.

Consider an arbitrary division of an arbitrary rectangle into $n$ regions, such that every region has exactly five neighboring regions. We translate this picture into a so-called [planar graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph): each of the $n$ regions then translates into a vertex/point, and there is a connecting edge between any two vertices/points that correspond to neighboring regions. The total number of edges is denoted $e$.

We only need facts on $e$ and $n$

> **Fact 1:** $~~~~2e=5n$

This can be seen by counting the touching vertex-edge pairs: every edge touches two vertices, and every vertex touches $5$ edges.

> **Fact 2:** $~~~~e\le3n-6$

This fact can be found (for instance) on the [wiki-page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) in the paragraph on maximal planar graphs.  If follows from the Euler formula for planar graphs.

Now by combining Facts 1 and 2, we get

> $5n/2~=~e~\le~3n-6$,

which implies $0\le n/2-6$ and hence $n\ge12$. Consequently, Lopsy's construction is best possible with respect to the number of used regions.