# Dissecting a square

Tags: geometry, optimization, graph-theory, polyomino, dissection

You are asked to dissect an $N \times N$ square into [polyomino pieces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino) such that each piece shares a portion of its boundary with exactly $D$ other pieces, and no piece has area exceeding $N$. This can be achieved for $D \le 5$.

For $D=2, 3, 4$ the smallest such squares are of size $2 \times 2$, $3 \times 3$, $4 \times 4$, respectively:
[image]

Find the smallest square for $D=5$.

Credit: inspired by [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8122/find-smallest-rectangle-divided-into-figures-so-each-figure-has-5-neighbours).

---

**EDIT / Bounty offer by Will Octagon Gibson:**

Two answers have already been posted using 8x8 squares and 16 polyominoes.

I plan to award a bounty of 100 if a correct answer is posted using a smaller square or fewer polyominoes.

I plan to increase the bounty to 200 if a correct answer is posted using a smaller square **AND** fewer polyominoes.

These offers will expire on November 30, 2023 at approximately 11:59 p.m. (my time).

Good luck!

---

Comment: Wasn't this proven by Gerhard in that other puzzle?

Comment: That answer is not a square, and it can't be trivially extended to a square, because you will have pieces with an area larger than N.

Comment: @Quark - Gerhard has proven that for $D=5$ you need to dissect into at least 12 pieces.

Comment: "and no piece has area exceeding N". Is this condition necessary?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I've found a solution for an 8x8 square. I do not know if it is the *minimum* solution or how to prove that:

> [image: 8x8]

It was definitely fun to try and find this! Took me a while. Excellent puzzle.

---

Some comments on how I got to the solution (Rather a chronology than a full deduction):

> - It has been proven in the other puzzle that *at least* 12 tiles would be needed.
>  - It was clear, that each piece has to have *at least* 2 squares.
>  - I was intuitively convinced that the solution would have a 4-fold rotational symmetry. (No proof for that whatsoever. More a 'feeling'.) So I set out with trying patterns in this symmetry. If I get 1/4th of the pieces in place, the other 3/4th would be correct automatically.
>  - I figured the *rim* would be the difficult part, as long-stretched tiles are needed, and their length is limited by the square-size. 
>  - So I first tried to create a 7x7 square with fitting tiles to the border and leaving room for 5 connections. 
>  [image: stp]
>  - This did not work out (because of the symmetry centre being 'left out'). So I then retried the same with a 8x8 grid, ending up with:
>  [image: Step]
>  - Trying to extend the colours towards the centre (always using 4-fold rotational symmetry on the extensions) I soon ran into obstacles, which forced me to 'shift' the outer rim to:
>  [image: step]
>  - And then it was just a matter of extending *inwards* and realizing that the number of tiles is not yet enough. Adding 4 colours did the trick.

Comment: Well done. This 16 pieces solution is almost certainly the minimum. There are alternative solutions with fewer pieces, but they typically have a 3-fold symmetry and require 3 pieces to cover the full boundary, thereby violating the requirement of the area not exceeding the linear dimension. Not a proof, but makes it pretty plausible smaller squares won't allow for a solution.

Answer (score 6):

It is also possible with rectangles.

> [image: square dissection]   or   [image: square dissection]

Comment: Nice. Didn't see those.

Answer (score 2):

A near miss for $D=5$ and $N=7$, with $12$ polyominoes and largest area $8$ instead of $\le 7$:

> [image]

The underlying $5$-regular connected planar graph is the [icosahedral graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_icosahedron#Icosahedral_graph).

Comment: +1 So close! Nice!